# Visual Studio Shared Dataset Strategy

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio solution with many projects.  Each project has SQL data associated with it.  As a result, I have a dataset for each project.  Is there a strategy to make a shared dataset so that if, say, my connection string changes, I don't have to go to dozens of projects to change it.

Comment: Wrap the dataset and associated logic/methods in a class library.  Then reference the class library in your projects.  You'll still need to configure the connection string for each consuming application, unless you code that into the class library.

Comment: Good idea!  I will try it.